# htaccess redirect part of filename

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have read several pages on redirecting files and urls with regex in htaccess, but nothing for what I am trying to achieve.

We have old file names such as /images/imagename-70-70.jpg - these have since been replaced by 100x100 versions, so the file name is now /images/imagename-100-100.jpg

We are getting a lot of errors in our log file for requests for the old filename. Is there any way to redirect based on splitting the file name up?

eg:

```
/images/$1-70-70.jpg should redirect to /images/$1-100-100.jpg
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when you go to 120x120 images? Are you going to have wrong names again? Unless there's a very good reason to have the image size part of the name, consider dropping the size. Likewise, will they always be JPEGs? You might want to have just `/images/imagename`, and in .htaccess add on the `-100-100.jpg` portion. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep this as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+images/(.+?)-70-70\.(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1-100-100.%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for this, but the redirect seems to omit the filename? I get `website.com/-100-100` ?

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. Corrected now, can you try again?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reload the post!! Will try that now. I also should have specified that I need the redirect from /images/ folder to /photos folder (so `website.com/images/000433-70-70.jpg` should redirect to `website.com/photos/000433-100-100.jpg`. Thank you v much for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^images/(\w+)-70-70\.jpg$ images/$1-100-100.jpg [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks - this seems to be the closest - the spec has changed slightly... I need to redirect from /images/xxx to /photos/xxx - I changed the path above but it's redirecting to the root path. eg `www.website.com/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/photos/xxx` any ideas??